# pivot table sql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

need help in error in database pivot. i have table tamed table_score like below:

```
|ID  | Subject | Score|
----------------------
|001 | 2GSLIG  | 80   |
|001 | 3ECITI  | 70   |
|002 | 2GSLIG  | 75   |
|002 | 3ECITI  | 85   |
-----------------------
```

then it should be pivotted into

```
|ID | 2GSLIG | 3ECITI |
-----------------------
|001|   80   |   70   |
|002|   85   |   75   |
-----------------------
```

my code is

```
SELECT
  ID,
  [2GSLIG] AS 2GSLIG,
  [3ECITI] AS 3ECITI
FROM
  (SELECT
     ID,
     Subject,
     Score
   FROM
     table_score) ps
PIVOT
 (SUM (Score)
  FOR Subject IN ( [2GSLIG], [3ECITI])) AS pvt
```

and it remains error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near '[ 2GSLIG ] AS 2GSLIG , [ 3ECITI ] AS 3ECITI FROM ( SELECT ID ,
Subject , Score F' at line 1
```

I am getting confuse with this, need help please. Thank you.

Comment: Haven't you mixed MySQL and MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about -

```
SELECT
    ID,
    SUM(IF(Subject = '2GSLIG', Score, 0)) AS `2GSLIG`,
    SUM(IF(Subject = '3ECITI', Score, 0)) AS `3ECITI`
FROM table_score
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: it encounter no error but the value returned is not the actual value, all value is remain 1 like figured below. can anybody tell me?
`|ID | 2GSLIG | 3ECITI |`
`-----------------------`
`|001|   1   |   1   |`
`|002|   1   |   1   |`
`-----------------------`

Comment: I was being lazy and did not read your question properly. Try it now.

Comment: Glad it works for you. When you have an answer that you are satisfied with please remember to accept it by clicking on the tick to the left of it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot the '' around 2GSLIG and 2ECITI in your aliases

```
SELECT ID, [2GSLIG] AS '2GSLIG', [3ECITI] AS '3ECITI' 
FROM (SELECT ID, Subject, Score FROM table_score ) AS ps PIVOT (SUM (Score) FOR Subject IN ( [2GSLIG], [3ECITI])) AS pvt
```